# SQL query to get 6 digits in the output value?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that gives the output like

```
select position_id from per_all_people_F
```

| Position_id |
| --- |
| FRT567 |
| GFT890 |
| GFT000876 |
| ABC00046 |

How do i make sure that after first 3 letters, the numbers have to be 6 digit.

Say for example :

`FRT567` should be `FRT000567`.
`GFT890` should be `GFT000890`
or `ABC00046` should be `ABC000046`

How can i tweak my query to accomodate this change?

Comment: "How do I make sure" normally means you are looking for a **constraint** on the column, so that invalid values can't be inserted (updated) in the first place. Is that what you need? The rest of your question sounds somewhat different - "given the data as it is, how can I modify it in the output of a query or report so it adds those zeros as needed?" Please clarify.

Comment: right('000000' + num,6) ?  where num will be all but the 1st 3 chars?  Not sure i get what you've tried/want.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav `RIGHT` is not a valid Oracle function and `+` is the addition operator in Oracle.

Comment: @MT0  apologies.  Didnt look at the Oracle tag. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(position_id,1,3)||LPAD(REGEXP_REPLACE(position_id,'\D+'),6,'0')
  FROM per_all_people_F
```

assuming your data format is similar to the presented samples at all.

- *first piece* : ordinary substring extraction for first three letters
- *second piece* : only digits are extracted from the string by using `REGEXP_REPLACE()`, then zeroes are left padded to the string upto six characters
- then concatenate the pieces by double pipe characters

Answer (score 1):

Using only standard string functions (no regular expressions) - split the string after the initial three letters and concatenate the required number of zeros in the middle. This will work correctly even when there are no digits to begin with (the entire input string is just the three letters).

```
with
  t (position_id) as (
    select 'FRT567'    from dual union all
    select 'GFT890'    from dual union all
    select 'GFT000876' from dual union all
    select 'ABC00046'  from dual union all
    select 'XQY'       from dual
  )
select position_id,
       substr(position_id, 1, 3) || rpad('0', 9 - length(position_id), '0') ||
       substr(position_id, 4) as valid_position_id
from   t;

POSITION_ID  VALID_POSITION_ID   
------------ --------------------
FRT567       FRT000567           
GFT890       GFT000890           
GFT000876    GFT000876           
ABC00046     ABC000046           
XQY          XQY000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple string functions and find the first 3 characters using `SUBSTR(position_id, 1, 3)` and then concatenate `||` it with the remaining characters left-padded with zeroes to a length of 6 using `LPAD(SUBSTR(position_id, 4), 6, '0')`. If you can have 3-characters strings then you can use `COALESCE` to make sure there are always 6 digits:

```sql
SELECT position_id,
       SUBSTR(position_id, 1, 3) || LPAD(SUBSTR(position_id, 4), 6, '0')
         AS expanded_position_id,

       -- Optional version for short strings
       SUBSTR(position_id, 1, 3)
       || COALESCE(LPAD(SUBSTR(position_id, 4), 6, '0'), '000000')
         AS expanded_position_id2
FROM   per_all_people_F
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE per_all_people_F (position_id) as
  SELECT 'FRT567'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GFT890'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GFT000876' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC00046'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | POSITION_ID | EXPANDED_POSITION_ID | EXPANDED_POSITION_ID2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | FRT567 | FRT000567 | FRT000567 |
> | GFT890 | GFT000890 | GFT000890 |
> | GFT000876 | GFT000876 | GFT000876 |
> | ABC00046 | ABC000046 | ABC000046 |
> | ABC | ABC | ABC000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae61c0812647f002c28503db941d1489)*